# Regex how to stop capturing if there is more than one space

Tags: regex

So I want to capture name and code from this kind of table :

```
|   2 | Aix en Provence (Gare SNCF)                        | QXB  |
|   3 | Ajaccio                                            | AJA  |
|   4 | Angers                                             | ANE  |
|   5 | Angers (Gare SNCF)                                 | QXG  |
```

With `\|\s+\d+\s\|\s([^|]+)\|\s(\w+)\s+\|` I can extract the whole line until `|`.

However I want to `trim` the first capture groupe.

So my question is how can I say a regex to stop capturing if there is more than one space between the words?

[Here you have a playground.](https://regex101.com/r/WqMMUL/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may turn the greedy `+` after `[^|]` character class to a lazy one and add a `\s*` (zero or more whitespaces) pattern right after it.

Use

```
\|\s+\d+\s*\|\s*([^|]+?)\s*\|\s*(\w+)\s+\|
                ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X39K8R/1).

Since the lazily quantified subpatterns are only tested after all the subsequent subpatterns fail to find a match, the whitespaces, formerly captured into Group 1, are now consumed with `\s*` pattern, and Group 1 gets rid of them.